# I'm having a hard time getting object keys within arrays elements

Tags: javascript, json

I'm newbie to REACT, and to code in general.
I'm having problems understanding how to get the value of key **date** from this JSON.
So far, I thought maybe a double nested for loop to push an array with the values of concerts, and they iterate using map. But still, the content of concerts is an Objects (why is so hard in React this? btw)
Can anyone give me a hand here?
I really want to learn how to get pair key value  from objects inside an array.

thanks in advance!

Here's my JSON.

```
[
     {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Blooming Fluorescence",
          "year": "2022",
          "concerts": [
               {
                    "1": {
                         "date": "15/11/2022",
                         "place": "sssss)",
                         "ensemble": {
                              "name": "rtyuaize",
                              "Players": [
                                   "Flute: OIUYT",
                                   "Oboe: OIUY",
                                   "C.B.Clarinet: 456789",
                                   "Accordion: KJHGF",
                                   "Violoncello: FGHJK"
                              ]
                         },
                         "program": "",
                         "FacebookEvent": "sssss",
                         "poster": ""
                    }
               },
               {
                    "2": {
                         "date": "27/01/2023",
                         "place": "Rübühne, Esse (DE)",
                         "ensemble": {
                              "name": "xxxxx",
                              "Players": [
                                   "Flute: xxxxxx",
                                   "Oboe: xxxxxx",
                                   "C.B.Clarinet: xxxxxx",
                                   "Accordion: xxxxxx",
                                   "Violoncello: xxxxxx"
                              ]
                         }
                    }
               }
          ],
          "instruments": "B.Fl, Ob, C.B.Cl, Acc, Vc",
          "electronics": true,
          "score": {
               "fullScore": "",
               "Parts": ""
          },
          "lnks": {
               "youtube": [],
               "soundcloud": [],
               "spotify": []
          },
          "commission": "",
          "video": true,
          "category": "chamber music",
          "video_by": "xxxxxx",
          "prizes": [],
          "press": [
               {
                    "blog": {
                         "language": "",
                         "link": ""
                    }
               }
          ]
     },
     {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Paradise (lush sensitivity digitally designed)",
          "year": "2022",
          "categeory": "solo",
          "concerts": [
               {
                    "1": {
                         "date": "28/03/2022",
                         "place": "Centre Culturel Italien, Paris (FR)",
                         "ensemble": {
                              "name": "xxxxxx",
                              "Players": [
                                   "Sheng: xxxxxx",
                                   "Electronics: xxxxxx"
                              ]
                         },
                         "program": "",
                         "FacebookEvent": "",
                         "poster": ""
                    }
               },
               {
                    "2": {
                         "date": "24/12/2022",
                         "place": "C-Lab (TW)",
                         "ensemble": {
                              "name": "xxxxxx",
                              "Players": [
                                   "Sheng: xxxxxx",
                                   "Electronics: xxxxxx"
                              ]
                         }
                    }
               },
               {
                    "3": {
                         "date": "25/12/2022",
                         "place": "C-Lab (TW)",
                         "ensemble": {
                              "name": "xxxxxx",
                              "Players": [
                                   "Sheng: xxxxxx",
                                   "Electronics: xxxxxx"
                              ]
                         }
                    }
               }
          ],
          "instruments": "Sheng (37 reed)",
          "electronics": true,
          "score": {
               "fullScore": "xxxxxx",
               "Parts": ""
          },
          "lnks": {
               "youtube": [],
               "soundcloud": [],
               "spotify": []
          },
          "commission": "",
          "video": false,
          "video_by": "",
          "prizes": [],
          "press": [
               {
                    "blog": {
                         "language": "",
                         "link": ""
                    }
               }
          ]
     }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A few `flatMap`s and `Object.values` will do it

```
const dates = data.flatMap(obj => obj.concerts.flatMap(concert => Object.values(concert).map(obj => obj.date)))
```

```js
const data = [
     {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Blooming Fluorescence",
          "year": "2022",
          "concerts": [
               {
                    "1": {
                         "date": "15/11/2022",
                         "place": "sssss)",
                         "ensemble": {
                              "name": "rtyuaize",
                              "Players": [
                                   "Flute: OIUYT",
                                   "Oboe: OIUY",
                                   "C.B.Clarinet: 456789",
                                   "Accordion: KJHGF",
                                   "Violoncello: FGHJK"
                              ]
                         },
                         "program": "",
                         "FacebookEvent": "sssss",
                         "poster": ""
                    }
               },
               {
                    "2": {
                         "date": "27/01/2023",
                         "place": "Rübühne, Esse (DE)",
                         "ensemble": {
                              "name": "xxxxx",
                              "Players": [
                                   "Flute: xxxxxx",
                                   "Oboe: xxxxxx",
                                   "C.B.Clarinet: xxxxxx",
                                   "Accordion: xxxxxx",
                                   "Violoncello: xxxxxx"
                              ]
                         }
                    }
               }
          ],
          "instruments": "B.Fl, Ob, C.B.Cl, Acc, Vc",
          "electronics": true,
          "score": {
               "fullScore": "",
               "Parts": ""
          },
          "lnks": {
               "youtube": [],
               "soundcloud": [],
               "spotify": []
          },
          "commission": "",
          "video": true,
          "category": "chamber music",
          "video_by": "xxxxxx",
          "prizes": [],
          "press": [
               {
                    "blog": {
                         "language": "",
                         "link": ""
                    }
               }
          ]
     },
     {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Paradise (lush sensitivity digitally designed)",
          "year": "2022",
          "categeory": "solo",
          "concerts": [
               {
                    "1": {
                         "date": "28/03/2022",
                         "place": "Centre Culturel Italien, Paris (FR)",
                         "ensemble": {
                              "name": "xxxxxx",
                              "Players": [
                                   "Sheng: xxxxxx",
                                   "Electronics: xxxxxx"
                              ]
                         },
                         "program": "",
                         "FacebookEvent": "",
                         "poster": ""
                    }
               },
               {
                    "2": {
                         "date": "24/12/2022",
                         "place": "C-Lab (TW)",
                         "ensemble": {
                              "name": "xxxxxx",
                              "Players": [
                                   "Sheng: xxxxxx",
                                   "Electronics: xxxxxx"
                              ]
                         }
                    }
               },
               {
                    "3": {
                         "date": "25/12/2022",
                         "place": "C-Lab (TW)",
                         "ensemble": {
                              "name": "xxxxxx",
                              "Players": [
                                   "Sheng: xxxxxx",
                                   "Electronics: xxxxxx"
                              ]
                         }
                    }
               }
          ],
          "instruments": "Sheng (37 reed)",
          "electronics": true,
          "score": {
               "fullScore": "xxxxxx",
               "Parts": ""
          },
          "lnks": {
               "youtube": [],
               "soundcloud": [],
               "spotify": []
          },
          "commission": "",
          "video": false,
          "video_by": "",
          "prizes": [],
          "press": [
               {
                    "blog": {
                         "language": "",
                         "link": ""
                    }
               }
          ]
     }
]

const dates = data.flatMap(obj => obj.concerts.flatMap(concert => Object.values(concert).map(obj => obj.date)))
console.log(dates)
```

But I have to say that this structure is a nonsense

You have an array which has objects with one property (1, 2, etc.) this is not ok

Removing the unnecessary nesting will makes things easier:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Blooming Fluorescence",
    "year": "2022",
    "concerts": [
      {
        "date": "15/11/2022",
        "place": "sssss)",
        "ensemble": {
          "name": "rtyuaize",
          "Players": [
            "Flute: OIUYT",
            "Oboe: OIUY",
            "C.B.Clarinet: 456789",
            "Accordion: KJHGF",
            "Violoncello: FGHJK"
          ]
        },
        "program": "",
        "FacebookEvent": "sssss",
        "poster": ""
      },
      {
        "date": "27/01/2023",
        "place": "Rübühne, Esse (DE)",
        "ensemble": {
          "name": "xxxxx",
          "Players": [
            "Flute: xxxxxx",
            "Oboe: xxxxxx",
            "C.B.Clarinet: xxxxxx",
            "Accordion: xxxxxx",
            "Violoncello: xxxxxx"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "instruments": "B.Fl, Ob, C.B.Cl, Acc, Vc",
    "electronics": true,
    "score": {
      "fullScore": "",
      "Parts": ""
    },
    "lnks": {
      "youtube": [],
      "soundcloud": [],
      "spotify": []
    },
    "commission": "",
    "video": true,
    "category": "chamber music",
    "video_by": "xxxxxx",
    "prizes": [],
    "press": [
      {
        "blog": {
          "language": "",
          "link": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Paradise (lush sensitivity digitally designed)",
    "year": "2022",
    "categeory": "solo",
    "concerts": [
      {
        "date": "28/03/2022",
        "place": "Centre Culturel Italien, Paris (FR)",
        "ensemble": {
          "name": "xxxxxx",
          "Players": [
            "Sheng: xxxxxx",
            "Electronics: xxxxxx"
          ]
        },
        "program": "",
        "FacebookEvent": "",
        "poster": ""
      },
      {
        "date": "24/12/2022",
        "place": "C-Lab (TW)",
        "ensemble": {
          "name": "xxxxxx",
          "Players": [
            "Sheng: xxxxxx",
            "Electronics: xxxxxx"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "date": "25/12/2022",
        "place": "C-Lab (TW)",
        "ensemble": {
          "name": "xxxxxx",
          "Players": [
            "Sheng: xxxxxx",
            "Electronics: xxxxxx"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "instruments": "Sheng (37 reed)",
    "electronics": true,
    "score": {
      "fullScore": "xxxxxx",
      "Parts": ""
    },
    "lnks": {
      "youtube": [],
      "soundcloud": [],
      "spotify": []
    },
    "commission": "",
    "video": false,
    "video_by": "",
    "prizes": [],
    "press": [
      {
        "blog": {
          "language": "",
          "link": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Blooming Fluorescence",
    "year": "2022",
    "concerts": [{
        "date": "15/11/2022",
        "place": "sssss)",
        "ensemble": {
          "name": "rtyuaize",
          "Players": [
            "Flute: OIUYT",
            "Oboe: OIUY",
            "C.B.Clarinet: 456789",
            "Accordion: KJHGF",
            "Violoncello: FGHJK"
          ]
        },
        "program": "",
        "FacebookEvent": "sssss",
        "poster": ""
      },
      {
        "date": "27/01/2023",
        "place": "Rübühne, Esse (DE)",
        "ensemble": {
          "name": "xxxxx",
          "Players": [
            "Flute: xxxxxx",
            "Oboe: xxxxxx",
            "C.B.Clarinet: xxxxxx",
            "Accordion: xxxxxx",
            "Violoncello: xxxxxx"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "instruments": "B.Fl, Ob, C.B.Cl, Acc, Vc",
    "electronics": true,
    "score": {
      "fullScore": "",
      "Parts": ""
    },
    "lnks": {
      "youtube": [],
      "soundcloud": [],
      "spotify": []
    },
    "commission": "",
    "video": true,
    "category": "chamber music",
    "video_by": "xxxxxx",
    "prizes": [],
    "press": [{
      "blog": {
        "language": "",
        "link": ""
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Paradise (lush sensitivity digitally designed)",
    "year": "2022",
    "categeory": "solo",
    "concerts": [{
        "date": "28/03/2022",
        "place": "Centre Culturel Italien, Paris (FR)",
        "ensemble": {
          "name": "xxxxxx",
          "Players": [
            "Sheng: xxxxxx",
            "Electronics: xxxxxx"
          ]
        },
        "program": "",
        "FacebookEvent": "",
        "poster": ""
      },
      {
        "date": "24/12/2022",
        "place": "C-Lab (TW)",
        "ensemble": {
          "name": "xxxxxx",
          "Players": [
            "Sheng: xxxxxx",
            "Electronics: xxxxxx"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "date": "25/12/2022",
        "place": "C-Lab (TW)",
        "ensemble": {
          "name": "xxxxxx",
          "Players": [
            "Sheng: xxxxxx",
            "Electronics: xxxxxx"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "instruments": "Sheng (37 reed)",
    "electronics": true,
    "score": {
      "fullScore": "xxxxxx",
      "Parts": ""
    },
    "lnks": {
      "youtube": [],
      "soundcloud": [],
      "spotify": []
    },
    "commission": "",
    "video": false,
    "video_by": "",
    "prizes": [],
    "press": [{
      "blog": {
        "language": "",
        "link": ""
      }
    }]
  }
]

const dates = data.flatMap(obj => obj.concerts.flatMap(concert => concert.date))
console.log(dates)
```

Comment: thanks @konrad. I've learned so much from your answer. I'd love to learn also how not to produce a nonsense JSON. Most likely, I'll do that in a hard way considering I'm self-teaching how to do it. If you have any proposition, I'm eager to read. Cheers!